# Cubist regression under rpy2: "subscript out of bounds" error

Tags: python, r, rpy2

When I use rpy2 to do the Cubist regression.I met the error:

```
Error in strsplit(tmp, "\"")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I try to Use as.matrix to change the data format,but it's still unwork.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
Cubist = importr('Cubist')
lattice = importr('lattice')
r = robjects.r
# 准备样点数据
dt = r('mtcars')
Z = FloatVector(dt[3])
X = FloatVector(dt[5])
X1 = FloatVector(dt[6])
T = r['cbind'](X,X1)

regr = r['cubist'](x=T,y=Z,committees=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a matrix, the `x` argument to `cubist()` seems to require a `dimnames` attribute.

Setup in R:

```
library(Cubist)

dt = mtcars
Z = dt[, 4]
X = dt[, 6]
X1 = dt[, 7]
```

Now compare this (reproduces your error):

```
> T = cbind(dt[, 6], dt[, 7])
> str(T)
 num [1:32, 1:2] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
> cubist(x=T, y=Z, committees=10)
cubist code called exit with value 1
Error in strsplit(tmp, "\"")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

vs.

```
> T = cbind(X, X1)
> str(T)
 num [1:32, 1:2] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "X" "X1"
> cubist(x=T, y=Z, committees=10)

Call:
cubist.default(x = T, y = Z, committees = 10)

Number of samples: 32
Number of predictors: 2

Number of committees: 10
Number of rules per committee: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

There are multiple ways to ensure the dimnames get attached via `rpy2`. One easy way with your code is simply to explicitly name the variables:

```
In [15]: T = r['cbind'](X=X,X1=X1)

In [16]: print(r['str'](T))
 num [1:32, 1:2] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "X" "X1"
<rpy2.rinterface.NULLType object at 0x7f0d7c0f5608> [RTYPES.NILSXP]

In [17]: print(r['cubist'](x=T,y=Z,committees=10))

Call:
cubist.default(x = structure(c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46,
 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175,
 335, 109), committees = 10L)

Number of samples: 32
Number of predictors: 2

Number of committees: 10
Number of rules per committee: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: My major is remote sensing. Next, I need to calculate the remote sensing image data. When I read the image with GDAL, how to transform it into data format of R for Cubist prediction?

Comment: dt = gdal.Open("H:/bathmetry/GF6/cart/layer_stac")
blue = dt.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0,0,dt.RasterXSize, dt.RasterYSize)
green = dt.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray(0,0,dt.RasterXSize, dt.RasterYSize)    Blue = np.array(blue)
B = Blue.ravel()
Green = np.array(green)
G = Green.ravel()   X_test = np.vstack((B,G))

Comment: I filed this as an issue on the Cubist project page: https://github.com/topepo/Cubist/issues/24